# Project Euler Q3 JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My code is as follows:

```
function is_prime(num) {
    for(i=2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


};

var total = 600851475143,
    b = 2,
    storemax = 0;

function max_prime(total) {
    if(total % b === 0) {
        storemax = total / b;
        if (is_prime(storemax) = true) {
            console.log(storemax);
        } else {
            b += 1;
            max_prime(total);
        }
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been stuck on this for a while... trying to do the odin project web programming course.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Explain more clearly your aim

Comment: This may or may not be the case, but you wrote `if(is_prime(storemax)=true)` in your code, which I believe you meant `if(is_prime(storemax)==true)`.

Comment: You should use `===` to compare both value and type. Otherwise, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is found in your `max_prime` function

```
if (is_prime(storemax) = true) {
```

Here you are using an assignment operator when you should be using a comparison operator

Change this to

```
if (is_prime(storemax === true) {
```

This will check if the value of `is_prime(storemax)` is equal to `true`.

Also, JavaScript functions follow a lowerCamelCase convention. Change `is_prime` to `isPrime` and `max_prime` to `maxPrime`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I made the revisions but it still wont display anything when I have the document.write(storemax).... Any ideas?